# Why can't i connect my device in first... it is taking to many attempts for adb?

Tags: android, flutter, usb-debugging

i want to connect my android device through adb command line tool, But it does connect my device(through wifi debugging) to my laptop easily, it is taking too much attempts to connect and sometime does not connect. I am on same network, even connected with usb and usb debugging is also on.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9zmh.png)

Comment: I have seen similar scenarios that turned out to be a duplicate IP address on the network. You can easily find this by disconnecting your device and trying to ping the IP address. If it still responds you will know that the IP is already setup in another device!

Comment: I have checked my device ip address in settings it is legit.